# Import | Export Dataflow - Profiles Progress Percentage No longer displaying

Tags: magento, import, progress, dataflow

Currently our Dataflow profiles are not giving a progress percentage anymore.
It simply carries out the import and then show up all the errors. Previously it would show the progress which was nice.

Not a major issue but it would be nice to have some feedback.